# PHP Regex Help for Parsing Price from a String

Tags: php, regex

I know this topic has been covered to some degree, but after a few days I'm still having trouble figuring out the best way to parse a price from a block of text.

Here's are some examples:
This car is $15k and has $200 in upgrades
Those belts are USD 500.00 and I'm asking 50 for shipping

My approach has been to do three separate Regex matches:

1. To find the prices that are abbreviated with a K
2. To find the prices with a prefix
3. To find the prices with a suffix

## look for dollars with thousands abbreviated

```
preg_match_all('/^[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?(k)+$/', 
                    strtolower($description), $price_array1);
```

## look for dollars with prefixes

```
preg_match_all('/^(\$|\$ |price|price |price is |price:|price: |us|us |usd|usd |asking|asking |wanting|wanting |want|want |sgd|euro|euro |£|£ |€|€ |gbp|gbp |cdn|cdn |)+[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/', strtolower($description), $price_array2);
```

## look for dollars with suffixes

```
preg_match_all('/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)( eur|eur| firm| obo| shipped| \$|\$| €|€| £|£| gbp|gbp| dollar| aud)+/', strtolower($description), $price_array3);
```

But actually none of these seems to be working. I think I have my Regex correct? But not sure why they're not matching anything. 
I will admit I'm a bit confused about whether I should use ^ and $ but I've tried it with and without and it doesn't seem to make a difference. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `^` means the start of the original string and `$` means the end of the original string. If you add them in, of course you won't be able to match just some token inside the string.

Comment: Please note that we in germany uses something like: 1.999,99€

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to **strictly** match money-like numbers (it will not notice any prefix or suffix, even k for thousand):

`/(?<![0-9.,])(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]*)?)(?![0-9.,])/`

It will accept `34563745,34534`, `283947982.234`, `283.432`, `234424.`, `4234,4324`, `2.234.434,23442`, `3,234,234.234`, `324849000`. But it will reject `.453985`, `..,.,.434.,.34`, `234,43.234`, `23467,4443.234`.

The following will match **case-insensitive** prefix and with k (for thousand), aside from plain numbers:

`/(?<= |^)(?:(?i)(?:\$|USD) *)?(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]*)?)(?:(?i)k)?(?![0-9.,])/`

If you want to add more prefix, you can change this part of the regex:

`(?:\$|USD)`

Just add more prefix, without leading or trailing space. The regex will try to match even if there are many spaces.

The following will **only** match number with suffix (with optional thousand indicator):

`/(?<= |^)(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]*)?)(?:(?i)(?:k )? *(?:\$|USD))(?= |$)/`

Same as above if you want to add more suffix.

Test input and to [try it out](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html):

`Here's are some examples: This car is $15k and has $200 in upgrades Those belts are USD 500.00 and I'm asking 50 for shipping 345,345.45 495.344,424 ..,5435 878,543.455.345 345345435.545 234728394,34345 345, 453. 0.4355 .453 sdfsd usd 23423423K`

Comment: Wow - thank you! It's going to take me all week to figure this out. Just in case anyone here's what I'm using for the suffix: preg_match_all('/(?<= |^)(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]*)?) *(?:\$|usd|eur|euro|euros|firm|obro|€|£|gbp|dollar|aud|cdn|sgd)+(?= |$)/', strtolower($description), $price_array3); and this for the prefix: preg_match_all('/(?<= |^)(?:(?i)(?:\$|usd|price:|euro|£|€|gbp|cdn|sgd) *)+(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]*)?)(?:(?i)k)?(?![0-9.,])/', strtolower($description), $price_array1);