# Regex: Extract digits, before comma, after dollar sign, before percentage

Tags: python, regex, math

Was trying to keep this simple but I think I've complicated the regex now:

Basically, I want to remove all digits from a string - but taking into consideration that there may be a comma sign or a decimal.

Examples:

```
$13 -> 13
$13.95 -> 13
$1,300 -> 1300
$ 13 -> 13
Only 3 left -> 3
34 sold -> 34
34% -> 34
(45%) -> 45
($14) -> 14
£13 -> 13 (unicode u00A3)
```

Current regex in python:

```
re.match(ur"\$?\u00A3?(?:\s+)?((\d+)\,?(\d+)?)\%?(?:\.[0-9]*)?", value)
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872639/php-regex-help-for-parsing-price-from-a-string/10872780#10872780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a non-regex based solution?

```
>>> s = '$1,300'
>>> ''.join([x for x in s if x.isdigit()])
'1300'
```

This should work for all of your examples, except for `$13.95 -> 13` which I need clarification on the reasoning.  If you need to recognise negative numbers, floats, scientific notation etc you would have to tweak it.

Comment: This was the problem I was having upon which I found my self heading down the road to complexity. In some cases the data will be imported such as $13.95, in which I only need the whole number. I was thinking - check for the presence of a "." and if it exists extract only the digits before it.

Comment: Note that some countries use a decimal `,` instead of a `.`.  How will you tell the difference between $15,000 and $1,50 ?

Comment: Hmm, It'd be rare to see $1,50 -> $150, so I guess if there are only two digits after the , then it is a float, in most cases comma is used for $1,500 $10,000 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Works for every case. Used some lookbehind for the `.` thing

```
>>> u''.join(re.findall(ur'(?<!\.|\d)(\d+)', '$13.95'))
'13'
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match everything perfectly:

`'\$?([0-9,]+)[.%]?'`

Literal meaning:

- Can have a dollar sign
- grab all numbers and commas `[0-9,]` that are there.
- stop if theres no more numbers, a `.` or a `%` appears.

Comment: Thanks - How would I append/prepend other prefixes such as pound, euro etc

Comment: I'm not sure where some country's currencies are meant go (before/after), but replace the currency symbol where i put `@@@` in this:

`'\@@@?([0-9,]+)[.%@@@]?'`. Just means it can be `$32` or `32$`, for example, if you used `$` in both places.

Comment: get rid of the `''` around it. should run as `function(\$?([0-9,]+)[.%]?)`. I tested using pythonregex.com